# thumbnail type images?

Tags: visualforce, formula-field

I'm trying to integrate amazon S3 with SalesForce, I did it with the toolkit. When it says to
upload image, it shows the image to a bigger size which I do not want. How do i resize and have thumbnails?.

Pressing my head onto this from many days. They have taken image with the formula field under the `<script >` . Like ,they have a VF page called **'S3Preview'** where following is the code

```
<apex:page standardController="AWS_S3_Object__c" >
   <script>window.location.href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/
     {!AWS_S3_Object__c.Bucket_Name__c}/{!AWS_S3_Object__c.File_Name__c}";</script>
</apex:page>
```